# GraphQL API for ExpressionEngine

Tags: add-on

I just started using Expression Engine and it looks promising, but I am a bit lost with the addons ecosystem.

I have been searching around for a GraphQL integration with EE but I can't find one.

Do you know if there is an existing solution that allows consuming EE data via GraphQL?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help - https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/reinos-webservice